# Python Pandas - Scrape Multiple Tables from Multiple URLs into One Combined Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm new to Python.

I'm trying to scrape multiple tables from pages on a website. I want to make a dataframe from each table and combine all of the dataframes together into one large, combined dataframe.

Here are the steps I've completed so far:

1. Import packages
2. Open website and login
3. Jump to the page with the data
4. Add numbers to dictionary and loop through them to build the url for each page. The number starting with zeros are strings so the zero doesn't get dropped.

This is where I'm stuck. I can create one dataframe, but I'm having trouble creating a dataframe for EACH table and combining them together. I've tried the append function, but I end up with one dataframe so I must be missing something.

To clarify, I have about 700 urls. The urls are at the same website, but each page has a unique 4 digit number at the end of the url. I'm able to loop through each url using the code below. As each url is opened, I want to create a dataframe from the table at that url. Then I want to combine all of the dataframes into one large dataframe.

I hope this is clear. Any help is appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
DRIVER_PATH = 'C:\\Path to chromedriver.exe'
from selenium.webdriver import chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Path to chromedriver.exe')
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#open website 
driver.get('https://website.com')

#Login to website
element = driver.find_element_by_id('txtUID')
element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys("userID")
element = driver.find_element_by_id('txtPWD')
element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys("userPW")
import time
time.sleep(1)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('Send')
element.click()

#Jump to detail page
driver.get('https://DetailPage')
   
numbers = ['0101','0110','0130','0140','0150','0160','0170','0172','0180','0184','0185','0186','0190','0193','0203','0211','0213','0240','0260','0261','0270','0274','0280','0281','0285','0290','0300','0302','0310','0320','0340','0380','0412','0440','0490','0500','0540','0560','0603','0610','0630','0635','0652','0660','0670','0680','0681','0690','0713','0721','0740','0742','0750','0761','0776','0784','0790','0794','0801','0802','0804','0810','0851','0863','0870','0871','0881','0884','0886',1030,1056,1060,1090,1100,1170,1176,1180,1183,1194,1220,1230,1240,1251,1255,1260,1270,1290,1321,1360,1370,1405,1430,1441,1460,1501,1513,1522,1530,1560,1632,1650,1680,1686,1701,1711,1720,1740,1750,1760,1780,1790,1800,1806,1810,1820,1850,1860,1870,1900,1901,1903,1905,1917,1931,1940,1943,1950,1970,1972,1974,2002,2003,2060,2070,2072,2083,2100,2108,2110,2118,2121,2124,2127,2142,2170,2171,2180,2202,2203,2211,2212,2240,2260,2290,2302,2315,2321,2322,2332,2340,2341,2350,2360,2362,2380,2410,2440,2450,2510,2600,2720,2721,2725,2740,2760,2764,2801,2810,2811,2821,2824,2825,2830,2832,2850,2855,2860,2861,2862,2870,2874,2912,2930,2940,2943,2960,2961,2965,2970,2971,2992,3000,3003,3004,3012,3013,3014,3015,3022,3024,3025,3026,3027,3031,3032,3034,3040,3044,3045,3050,3051,3060,3070,3090,3120,3144,3160,3171,3172,3176,3190,3202,3203,3210,3220,3223,3250,3260,3261,3271,3275,3276,3283,3291,3296,3301,3306,3311,3313,3316,3326,3333,3340,3342,3343,3344,3350,3351,3352,3354,3357,3362,3363,3364,3371,3386,3390,3398,3461,3491,3523,3524,3531,3540,3560,3570,3581,3610,3620,3660,3661,3700,3702,3711,3715,3720,3725,3731,3740,3741,3783,3800,3810,3811,3830,3836,3850,3880,3881,3950,3961,3970,4016,4020,4021,4022,4023,4050,4052,4110,4122,4200,4210,4230,4243,4271,4305,4310,4313,4322,4324,4400,4403,4404,4411,4414,4416,4421,4422,4431,4432,4440,4470,4490,4501,4510,4511,4512,4521,4526,4530,4532,4541,4560,4580,4607,4620,4621,4622,4623,4624,4635,4636,4650,4651,4660,4681,4684,4690,4695,4715,4730,4737,4754,4770,4790,4793,4805,4806,4810,4813,4821,4822,4823,4830,4833,4834,4835,4836,4850,4881,4884,4902,4920,4942,4952,4955,5000,5010,5040,5070,5080,5110,5200,5220,5300,5301,5310,5320,5321,5340,5354,5370,5371,5390,5430,5431,5440,5441,5460,5486,5490,5510,5511,5521,5540,5541,5590,5594,5595,5630,5710,5850,5990,6001,6002,6004,6013,6014,6016,6017,6020,6030,6031,6043,6045,6051,6062,6066,6071,6090,6111,6135,6160,6182,6183,6220,6230,6265,6270,6300,6322,6334,6410,6412,6414,6480,6520,6560,6601,6603,6660,6780,6811,6814,6850,6860,6880,7000,7011,7031,7070,7081,7190,7222,7236,7360,7401,7414,7472,7500,7521,7525,7526,7534,7535,7552,7553,7560,7561,7570,7583,7587,7602,7610,7620,7623,7670,7702,7704,7706,7707,7711,7737,7738,7745,7753,7756,7763,7770,7780,7800,7820,7821,7823,7826,7837,7843,7850,7851,7852,7860,7872,7875,7876,7880,7882,7884,7940,7960,7970,7976,7986,7990,8000,8003,8007,8008,8010,8012,8013,8022,8025,8030,8040,8045,8046,8050,8091,8130,8137,8140,8150,8161,8200,8240,8290,8320,8321,8331,8332,8340,8346,8367,8370,8413,8440,8450,8451,8461,8465,8501,8502,8514,8520,8521,8522,8526,8530,8546,8565,8570,8571,8572,8582,8630,8640,8750,8820,8902,8904,8910,8914,8947,8970,9004,9010,9013,9014,9016,9040,9048,9050,9060,9061,9062,9080,9081,9120,9122,9132,9150,9153,9171,9172,9175,9200,9201,9202,9206,9211,9214,9221,9232,9234,9240,9246,9251,9253,9262,9270,9272,9300,9310,9321,9330,9331,9340,9371,9390,9402,9440,9450,9452,9453,9454,9455,9456,9460,9461,9470,9490,9491,9500,9505,9510,9511,9514,9530,9545,9550,9580,9581,9590,9591,9593,9701,9706,9723,9725,9730,9732,9740,9743,9750,9760,9770,9800,9802,9820,9822,9831,9844,9846,9861,9876,9910,9921,9930]

str = 'https://DetailPage={}'

for number in numbers:
    urls = str.format(number)
    print(urls)
    driver.get(urls)
    html = driver.page_source
    df = pd.read_html(html)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

in code `df = pd.read_html(html)` you basically created a new data.frame and overwrite previous results.

So you shall do something like:

```
result_df = []  # Create an empty list

for number in numbers:
    # Create url and get html page here

    result_df.append( pd.read_html(html) ) # Append generated dataframe from each html page to the list
```

Now review each generated dataframe, and see if they are correct. You can do this through manual checking `result_df[0]` etc.

If all correct, try to merge each dataframe together:
` final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for df in result_df:
final_df = final_df.append( df )

## final_df is what you are looking for.

`

By the way, `str` is reserved string type in python, and `str = 'https://DetailPage={}'` is not best pratice. The simplest way to create the url is that within the for loop:

```
url = f'https://DetailPage={number}'
```

The `f` prefix of the string tells python to create the string with the variable `number`. For example, if number is '0101', then url will be 'https://DetailPage=0101'

Comment: Daniel result_df.append( pd.read_html(html) ) prints an empty DataFrame.

Comment: You can try initialize result_df into a list. After the loop, it is going to be a list of dataframe from each iteration. Check if these dataframes are what you want and then find a way to merge them into one dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I’m a beginner to Python. The initial approach you suggested did not work for me, but it possible that I’m missing something. Could you provide code samples on your suggestions and explain how they could be integrated into my current code?

Comment: Sorry. Just realized that DataFrame.append(...) would return a new dataframe. And since no variable is storing that result, the merged dataframe is discarded. See updated code and if it solves your problem.